# I tried finding answers to this question but I didn't find any. I have an issue installing quick.db on Visual Studio Code v1.50.1

Tags: discord.js, better-sqlite3, quick.db

I'm creating a Discord Bot with discord.js v12 and I wanted to use quick.db for a DataBase but It keeps saying there was a problem installing `better-sqlite3@7.1.1` script. I tried doing `npm i better-sqlite3@7.1.1` and `npm i better-sqlite3` but it keeps saying that it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some of the error messages you are getting when you try to install the packages?

Comment: I found the issue and it works now. Sorry for bothering. If anyone searched this question, go to this page: https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md